# installing python-ldap on windows with cygwin (fails on gcc)

Tags: python, windows, gcc, pip, python-ldap

I have a virtual windows machine where I'm trying to install Python packages.

I've never used Windows before, so I started by installing Cygwin and used that to install the other packages I'd need.

At first I tried installing Python2.7 from Python.org, but eventually read that it was better for using GCC to use the one from Cygwin.

```
$ python -c "import math; print math.sqrt(4)"  # seems like all is well
```

Here's the install line (`setup-x86_64.exe` is the Cygwin installer binary):

```
$ ./setup-x86_64.exe -q -P wget -P gcc-g++ -P make -P python2.7 
$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ which pip
/usr/bin/pip
$ which g++
/usr/bin/g++
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

Then I ran the following:

```
$ pip install python-ldap

...lots of lines...

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-D1mVYX/python-ldap/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-3_5lF9-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-D1mVYX/python-ldap/
```

This is weird since I know (from above) that gcc & g++ are working just fine!

Anyone know how I can install `python-ldap` properly with `pip`?

Thanks!